# jQuery Validation plugin DOB field custom validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Suppose I have a date of birth field that I want to validate.

day / month/ year

Now I want to validate these 3 fields all AT THE SAME TIME.
I  mean if the user has still focus in any of these 3 fields, do not validate just yet. When he leaves all of them, validate the date.

Seem pretty easy, I can do :

```
 $('#dayInput').is(':focus')
```

for all the three fields, then check if one of them is true...
But this fails in a very interesting way. Seem to me that the jQuery validation plugin validates the elements in between the "inFocus" and "out of focus" events.

So, if I am in the year input and then move to the month input, between these two events none out of the three inputs are "focused" and I can't tell if the user left the 3 dob inputs of is still in one of them.

Is there a way to work-around this?

P.S. I can't register event handlers btw in the extra method that I am going to add, because they will be registered too late. Suppose I am in the day input, leave it => validation kicks in, the handlers (focus and blur get registered), but it's too late, the previous event is skipped.

I hope I make some sense here.

Comment: Where is your relevant code?  The form's HTML?  The jQuery for `.validate()`?  Your verbal explanation makes sense... but the part about how you've set this up and what you've already tried is very lacking in code and clarity.  I have no idea what "checking if `$('#dayInput').is(':focus')` is true" even means... there is no context with how you've used it or where you've inserted it.  And why use three fields to capture a date when you can use one field and validate the input for a `date` format?

Comment: @Sparky true. I did not want to show any code, because I wanted to hear some ideas. I really thought that some code that I tried would only spoil the problem. Anyhow, I can't use one single input because this is just the way it is. There are 3 fields for dob and they will not change.

Comment: How does providing useful and relevant information _"spoil the problem"_? This is not a guessing contest, nor is it about throwing ideas around to see what sticks. It's about concise answers to concise questions. Please fix your OP so people can help you.

Comment: @Sparky I think you are right, I was trying to jump over my head. Thx for the time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to trigger validation when a field loses focus, then when exactly?  (You cannot specify a group of fields to trigger validation when they lose focus collectively.) Only when you click the `submit` button?  If so, try these options...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        onfocusout: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        // your other options
    });

});
```

Form will only validate when you click `submit`.

**Working Demo:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/CQnRn/**

Documentation:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

---

A reasonable alternative would be to validate a single field for the date instead of three.

```
<input type="text" name="birthdate" />
```

rules option:

```
rules: {
  birthdate: {
    required: true,
    date: true
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LRAgX/

Comment: I will upvote this for the effort - thank you for that, but this is not what I wanted. I will however, present a small example to make things far simpler.

Comment: @Eugene, That may not be what you wanted but it may be the best you can get.  I've never heard of making the `.validate()` plugin ignore `focusout` and `keyup` events on individual elements only to trigger validation on `focusout` of a group of elements.  I wouldn't even attempt further assistance until I see the relevant HTML & jQuery code of where you're at.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the "and" operator "`&&`" like

```
if ($('#dayinput').change() && $('#monthinput').change() && $('#yearinput').change()) {
$('#myform').validate(); 
}
```

Comment: a bit confusing your answer. Suppose I just edited the day field and moved to the month field. What next? How am I supposed to validate or not according to your answer. May be I understood something wrong?

Comment: i thought the answer marked as solution is not what you were asking for. I guess you want to validate those fields before clicking any button but after writing into every field. So you could check if every input has changed and if so trigger the validation

Comment: yup, that is what i wanted. it turns out it is not possible with the plugin, si i dropped the idea at all.